# Can I have multiple users in SQLCipher?

Tags: c++, sqlite, authentication, database-connection, sqlcipher

I am using SQLCipher in a c++ project. It has multiple users and each one has to have their own database credentials. Can SQLCipher do this for me? If yes, please leave a sample code. If no, please share your opinions of how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. It looks like SQLCipher uses a key derivation function to turn your password into a key that is applied per page of the SQLite database.

What you can do instead is the usual trick to enable multi-party encryption:

1. Encrypt the database with a completely random key `k`;
2. Store tuples of `(user, encrypt(k, user_key))` in a file next to the database.
   `user_key` can in turn be generated from a password using a key derivation function.

Comment: Thank you. What would you recommend to use to avoid hard coding `k`?

Comment: Generate it randomly when you initialize the database. Users will never see it anyway.

Comment: But I have to keep it somewhere. Should I derive it from the MAC address?

Comment: That depends on your threat and/or business model.